# Are there any branching dialogue editors (preferably for Mac)?

Tags: editors, macos

I'm currently looking for a branching dialogue editor that allows me to prepare all the dialogue, export it into an XML format that then can be parsed by Unity 3D.

The only editor I found until now is [Chat Mapper](http://www.chat-mapper.com/), which is Win only. Is there something similar for Mac?

Even if there is nothing for the Mac – what would be other alternatives to Chat Mapper, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a mind mapping utility to help you flesh out your conversation branches? There are plenty of free and paid ones for mac

Most conversation builders seem to be tightly coupled to a specific game development engine, and there doesn't seem to be (m)any free standing alternatives.

Since you're looking at using Unity, look for existing Unity conversation makers, such as [ConversationMaker](http://lemuria.org/projects/wiki/UnityConversationMaker) and [Conversation Engine](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/56860-Conversation-Engine-WIP).

Comment: Hm, I completely forgot about FreeMind, which does mind mapping nicely **and** produces XML files … that could be an idea. And thank you for mentioning ConversationMaker … I did not know about, checking that out right now. Great suggestions!

Comment: Conversation Engine has since moved to Github: https://github.com/tvogt/conversationengine

Answer (score 1):

You can try [inky](https://www.inklestudios.com/ink/) by inkle studios, creators of 80 days around the world. It is very simple but let’s you build complex branching conversations.

There is Unity integration as well.